# Get selection of document list items for display on homepage

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8

I have followed the article :-

https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/tutorials/creating-basic-site/articles-parent-and-article-items/

This gets me a list of article items for a particular article parent. However if I had a number of article items under various article parents (eg news items, features, reviews etc) How would I get the last 5 of any of those items for the homepage? (All the items would be of the same document type).

Answer (score 0):

Using the page you referenced above, simply add a .Take(5) to the end of the query like so:

```
@{
    var selection = Umbraco.Content(Guid.Parse("c4b9c457-7182-4cfb-a1af-f0211d67ea51"))
    .Children("articlesItem")
    .Where(x => x.IsVisible())
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate)
    .Take(5);
}
```

Comment: This just gets the children of the one parent. I want all items of document type "articlesItem" no matter what their parents.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  There is a Descendants() method that you can use instead of Children().

Comment: Note: The Decendents() can be slow if you have a lot of content.  Consider using XPATH or Examine if you are seeing performance issues or know that there will be a lot of content someday.